# How to handle serializing floats from C# into numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, json.net

I am using newtonsoft json to convert some custom classes into payloads for web requests.
We are using a hashing system to ensure data concurrency.

I am using SerializeObject with custom settings:
`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_report,settings);`

This is the settings that I am using:

```
public static JsonSerializerSettings GetJsonSettings(){
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
    settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
    settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
    settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    return settings;
}
```

When the serializer converts the object any floats are displayed with decimal points, including whole number floats. On the backend when js is reading the json payload when it converts floats to the js numbers any whole number floats lose their decimal point and trailing zeros:

This is one of the classes that is being serialized:

```
public class FlightLogEntry {
    public long timestamp;
    public Vector3 position;
    public float speedX;
    public float speedZ;
    public float speedMagnitude;
    public float battery;

    public FlightLogEntry() {

    }
}
```

1.02 => 1.02

Result of serialize in the program(C#):

```
{
    "timestamp": 230,
    "position": {
        "x": -15.07,
        "y": 2.009453,
        "z": -71.97
    },
    "speedX": 0.0,
    "speedZ": 0.0,
    "speedMagnitude": 0.0,
    "battery": 1379.98
}
```

1.0 => 1

Result of JSON.stringify(body) on the server(JS):

```
{
    "timestamp": 230,
    "position": {
        "x": -15.07,
        "y": 2.009453,
        "z": -71.97
    },
    "speedX": 0,
    "speedZ": 0,
    "speedMagnitude": 0,
    "battery": 1379.98
}
```

This was breaking our hash comparison checks, so what I did was make a custom converter to convert the floats on my end to trim the .0 on whole number floats. This corrected the hash mismatch but has introduced an issue on my end where when I write a backup to a file with the whole numbers trimmed, I cannot read them back as floats. They deserializer wants to read them as integers and throws an error.

Q: Is there a better way to handle the float 1.0 => 1 issue with js number?

Q: Is there a way to discern the "target" value in the ReadJson method of custom converters?

- For example: If my json has a integer, but the target object class has a float, can I detect that a float is needed then make the cast manually in the JsonConverter.ReadJson method?

Comment: `1.0` and `1` are the same in JS

Comment: Your hash comparison checks are too weak, JSON is not your problem, IMO you need to find a better method.

Comment: there is something weird going on here. What are you really trying to do? What do you mean by "data concurrency"? Did you mean "Data consistency"?

Comment: If you really need some help you have to show us at least something, your json or your code. But it is better if you show both. We are not making speculations here, we are offering a solution. And what javascript has to do with c#?

Comment: @Serge The backend is written in javascript my program is in C#. I am making a hash of the payload before sending. The backend is then also computing a hash on what it receives. In C# when I write the object to json, all the whole number floats are saved as 1.0, 7.0, etc so that is hashed. On the backend side when they are converting the json payload javascript reads the 1.0 and 7.0 as 1 and 7(no decimals) so their hash was computed differently. I will add some code and json examples to the post.

Comment: @JonasH Essentially the system has a local backup file in case someone is offline when their data is saved, this is written to a json file, that json is then hashed and submitted to the server with the hash in the web request header. The backend then computes it's own has of the data and compares it to the one I submit in the header.  When you are hashing the parsed json 1 and 1.0 are not the same so the hashes wouldn't match.

Comment: Depending on the precision you need, could convert all of your floats into integers (multiply by 100 and remove the decimal point for two decimal points, for example), send that in your json, and then simply convert it back to a decimal/float in your backend by dividing by 100 (for example). I've used this and seen it used in multiple banking apis when handling payment amounts.

Comment: This [NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vxPG81) serializes FlightLogEntry using both Json.NET and System.Text.Json.  As you can see Json.NET adds trailing zeros whereas the other output matches JavaScript JSON.stringify. So an alternative solution would be to use System.Text.Json when calculating the json hash.  Frankly though, the reason for using the hash eludes me as I've not seen this used elsewhere in the same way.

Comment: @Yogi The reason for the hash has to do with two of the requirements we have. If a user has an issue sending their data to the backend we store the json data encrypted locally to a file. This file lives for 30 days to help mitigate data loss. On each login to the program a subprocess checks the server for each saved file to see if the data exists on the server, the hash is being used as a way to confirm then delete the local file. This is because some users have hundreds of saved files and the api request counts are getting out of hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can convert floats without decimal part to integers. This way you you JavaScript json will be the same as c# json string.You can try this custom converter

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_report, new FloatJsonConverter());

public class FloatJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject o = JObject.FromObject(value);
        var floats = o.DescendantsAndSelf()
                    .Where(x => x.Type == JTokenType.Float)
                    .Select(x => (JProperty) x.Parent)
                    .ToList();
                    
        for (var i = 0; i < floats.Count(); i++)
        {
            var val = (float)floats[i];
            var intVal = (float)Math.Truncate(val);
            var decVal = Math.Abs((val - intVal));
            if (decVal <= 0.0000000000001) floats[i].Value = Convert.ToInt32(intVal);
        }
        o.WriteTo(writer);
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

you don't a special converter to deserialize int to float, since Newtonsoft.Json does it automatically.

Comment: This is essentially what I landed on after looking into available options. Instead of posting my own solution I will be accepting this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue the client and server needs to work on either the transmitted data, or the parsed objects.

The server could just hash the received json to catch any transmission errors, before actually doing any de serialization. Ofc, the transmission layer should already handle consistency, so I'm not sure how useful this would be.

Or both the server and client could to use a serialization method that is consistent to ensure the actual objects are the same. It should be possible to use json for this, but you would need to ensure the server and client use the exact same library, version of said library, culture, and settings. Json is not great for this since it is intended to be human readable, and humans usually do not care about things like `0` vs `0.0`, or whitespace.

I would think some sort of binary serialization would be less fragile, so that would probably be my preferred approach. You could use binaryWriter/reader and do manual serialization, that way you have full control. Or use something like protobuf .net and accept some risk that future versions might serialize messages slightly differently.